# Use-spare-network-capacity wrapper (network nice)

Tags: networking, nice

I would like to use my 100/100 Mbps connection for Tor. I want to give it all my spare capacity, but I do not want to have my connection slowed down by Tor the 1% of the time when I actually need the 100 Mbps.

I have Tor on a separate server connected to the LAN.

```
[TOR-server] [Host2] [Host3] ... [Hostn]
     |          |       |           |
     +----------+-------+-----------+
                    |
                 [Router1]
                    |
                 [Router2]
                    |
                [Internet]
```

`[Router1]`, `[Router2]` and `[Host2]` ... `[Hostn]` cannot be changed. The limiting link is typically between `[Router1]` and `[Router2]`.

Ideally I want to only slow down network to/from the `tor` process on `[TOR-server]` but it is acceptable if the network to/from the whole `[TOR-server]` is limited. I have been unable to find a `qdisc` that looks at round trip time to an external host.

How can I let Tor use all spare capacity, but slow down when others on the network need the bandwidth?

Is there a general tool for that? Maybe similar to `nice` for CPU usage?

I can see you could probably build it like this:

```
# Find close router
$hop2 = hop 2 of traceroute to 8.8.8.8
# Ping the $hop2 to look for signs of congestion
ping $hop2 &
while(true) {
  if(reply time < 2 * median(reply times)) {
    # latency normal
    sleep 1
  } else {
    suspend($bandwidth_using_program, 1 second)
  }
}
```

But is there already a well tested tool for this?

Comment: I think you need to read up on Queueing Disciplines (`qdisc`) and Traffic Shaping.  Useful link: [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://www.lartc.org/howto/).

Comment: @TobySpeight But that requires all traffic to go through the server. It does not.

Comment: Are you saying there's more than one point of connection to your 100M external link?   Normally there's one system on the boundary that's in a position to do traffic shaping.  It doesn't need to be the host originating the traffic.  And IIRC there are qdiscs that can use round-trip times to determine throttling of their traffic.

Comment: @TobySpeight There is only one point of connection (see drawing: [Router1]). But my question is not whether you can shape on a router, but whether you can shape traffic on the originating host without knowing how much bandwidth is available downstream this second. I give a blueprint for a possible solution - which might not be perfect, though.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're averse to doing this on one or both routers (which have the complete view of the traffic).  The only thing I can suggest with that constraint is to get an egress filter to write the IP TOS bits, but I've never done that, and it seems that TOS has been [superseded by something called DSCP](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header), so I'm obviously insufficiently current!

Comment: @TobySpeight Because the routers are not owned by me and they may not be running GNU/Linux at all. Nor do I own all of Host1..n.